# How to pass initial value to split view controller's detail?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uikit

Let's say that I have a split view controller with:
 1. Master view controller: a navigation controller with a view controller inside, which embeds a table view controller
 2. Detail view controller. It's dependant on some value that should be passed to it (otherwise it wouldn't work correctly, the app would crash)

Basically the detail view controller requires an extra initialization step and some value should be passed to it, otherwise the app would crash. Now I know how to pass this value when a table view row is clicked, but the problem is: how to perform this initialization the first time? I have to do it, otherwise the split view controller is already initialized with an associated detail view controller, which would crash if this value is not passed. Is there any callback to listen in order to pass this value?

Answer (score 1):

> Let say you have 2 View Controllers:
>
> 1. ListViewController which has a list of your data
> 2. DetailViewController which display the details of the data that you tapped from first ViewController
>
> So if you want to pass your data and set it to your ViewController's components, you can declare some variables to store those data and then you can set those data to your components in `override func viewDidLoad(){}`
>
> I hope this could answer your question and help.